# custom split function not working in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a custom function in pl/sql which splits a clob variable into set of strings on the basis of the separator provided but it is not working as intended please help me out in figuring the problem with the code.

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION                             SPLITCLOB (p_in_string clob, p_delim VARCHAR2) RETURN t_array
IS
  i       number :=0;
  pos     number :=0;
  lv_str  clob := p_in_string;

  Strings t_array:=t_array ();
Begin
  -- determine first chuck of string
  pos := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(lv_str,p_delim,1,1);

  If ( pos = 0) Then
    i := i + 1;
    strings.Extend();
    strings(i) := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(lv_str,1);
     RETURN strings;
  End If;
  -- while there are chunks left, loop
  WHILE ( pos != 0) LOOP
     -- increment counter
     i := i + 1;

     -- create array element for chuck of string
     strings.EXTEND();
     strings(i) := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(lv_str,1,pos-1);

     -- remove chunk from string
     lv_str := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(lv_str,pos+1,dbms_lob.getLength(lv_str));

     -- determine next chunk
     pos := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(lv_str,p_delim,1,1);

     -- no last chunk, add to array
     IF pos = 0 THEN
        strings.extend();
        strings(i+1) := lv_str;
     END IF;
  End Loop;

  -- return array
  RETURN strings;
End Splitclob;
```

here `t_array()` is custom type defiition of which is provided below

```
create or replace 
  TYPE "T_ARRAY" 
  AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with the code?
What have you tried to fix it?
What are the contents of the CLOB you are trying to extract data from?

Comment: There is a table which has a column named description having clob as content in it basically that contains audit_logs of the application we are using it for the analytics . Description in the table is of kind "order_id=383325; order_line_item=59; order_class_id=5749; subscription_code=5U12PFNCAU; start_date=01/12/2012; end_date=30/11/2013; date_override=null; license_available=-1; license_consumed=1; license_override=-1; order_class_status=0"

Comment: we are trying to get the various values by providing the separator ";" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a piece of code I wrote not a long time ago and it seems it works as you want. Note: it will also work if there is only a single item in the input parameter (I mean, the situation when there is no separator in the input is covered).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  TYPE T_ARRAY
  AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitclob (p_clob_in CLOB, p_delim VARCHAR2) RETURN t_array
AS
  v_buffer VARCHAR2(500);
  v_len NUMBER;
  v_offset NUMBER := 1;
  v_delim_pos NUMBER;
  v_amount NUMBER;
  v_result_array t_array := t_array();
BEGIN
  IF p_clob_in IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_len := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob_in);

    WHILE v_offset < v_len
    LOOP
      v_delim_pos := instr(p_clob_in, p_delim, v_offset);

      IF v_delim_pos = 0 THEN
        v_amount := v_len - v_offset + 1;
      ELSE
        v_amount := v_delim_pos - v_offset;
      END IF;

      dbms_lob.read(p_clob_in, v_amount, v_offset, v_buffer);
      v_offset := v_offset + v_amount + 1;

      v_result_array.EXTEND;
      v_result_array(v_result_array.LAST) := v_buffer;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  RETURN v_result_array;
END;
/

DECLARE
  v_array t_array;
BEGIN
  v_array := splitclob('order_id=383325; order_line_item=59; order_class_id=5749; subscription_code=5U12PFNCAU; start_date=01/12/2012; end_date=30/11/2013; date_override=null; license_available=-1; license_consumed=1; license_override=-1; order_class_status=0', ';');

  FOR v_i IN v_array.first..v_array.last
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_i || ' ' || v_array(v_i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output:

```
1 order_id=383325
2  order_line_item=59
3  order_class_id=5749
4  subscription_code=5U12PFNCAU
5  start_date=01/12/2012
6  end_date=30/11/2013
7  date_override=null
8  license_available=-1
9  license_consumed=1
10  license_override=-1
11  order_class_status=0
```

You have to take into account a situation when one of the tokens will be longer than 500 characters. Remember that `VARCHAR2` datatype in SQL context has a 4000 bytes limitation. If you know there won't be tokens longer than that, then you don't have to change anything.

Comment: Isn't the limit Oracle VARCHAR2 when used in SQL, 4000 bytes or characters? source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr06002.htm#SQLQR966

Comment: @IanCarpenter I guess I mixed up standard output's maximal line length with VARCHAR2's maximal length in bytes, will update my answer, thank you.